# bootstrap year picker doesn't pick year only

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

What I am trying to do is create a standalone year picker, no need to pick date. But below configuration of bootstrap is giving me drill down, once I select the year, It shows me month and than date. But I just want the selection to happen as soon as I click on year

### javascript

```
$scope.formats = ['yyyy','dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.dateFormat = $scope.formats[0];
$scope.popup = {
    opened : false
};

$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.popup.opened = true;
};
```

### html

```
 <p class="input-group input-group-unstyled" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
<input type="text" class="form-control  input-sm" id="year" name="year"
       uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"
       ng-model="year"
       is-open="popup.opened"
       min-mode="year" datepicker-mode="'year'"
       close-text="Close"
   />
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" ng-click="open($event)"></i>
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Please try to add a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed single quotes around minMode:"'year'" to minMode:"year" and solved the issue, strange behavior

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'datepicker-options' attribute to pass in the options, rather than the element attributes.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" 
   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" datepicker-options="{{datepickerOptions}}"
   is-open="opened" ng-focus="open($event)"
  date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
</input>
```

and

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = {
  datepickerMode:"year",
  minMode:"year",
  minDate:"minDate",
  showWeeks:"false",
};
```

Find the documentation here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Hope it helps you!

Comment: for some reason popup is not working with this option

Comment: Probably because it should be `uib-datepicker-popup` I have updated the answer.

Comment: can you please create a plunker or fiddle so I can have a look?

Comment: its working now i had to change    minMode:"'year'",
to   minMode:"year",

Answer (score 0):

varit05 made a small mistake:

datepicker-options="{{datepickerOptions}}"

should be:

datepicker-options="datepickerOptions"

since the datepicker-options is already in the angular's space.

Comment: I can't :-/ Error message: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"